# Integrate a picture in CV

Tags: diagrams, moderncv

Currently I'm writing a CV in LaTeX, the only struggle is to add the picture. I would like to add it under the line on the right side next to the personal details. Is there any way to do this? Looking forward to your ideas!

[image]

This is my document for now.  I changed the command `\makecvtitle` because I wanted it to look different, but I think that will be the reason why the picture is not working.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\moderncvtheme{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\moderncvicons{marvosym}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=25mm,headsep=10mm, footskip=-0mm}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3,5cm}

\title{SEA Online Marketing Spezialist}
\firstname{Rebecca}
\familyname{Rekker}
\address{XXXXXXXXX}{XXXXXXXXX}
\mobile{XXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\email{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}

\begin{document}


\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\upshape}
 \renewcommand{\makecvtitle}{%
  \recomputecvlengths%
  \makecvfoot%
\raggedright{{\raggedright\namefont{\color{color2}\@firstname}} {\raggedright\namefont{\color{color2}\@familyname}}}
\\[-.35em]%
  {\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}
\\[1.25em]
  {\raggedright\Large{\color{color2}\@title}}
\\

}% 

\makecvtitle

\section{Persönliche Daten}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example compilable (MWE). That includes the documentclass and relevant packages.

Comment: Please provide a MWE. Moreover what class you are using for building CV? However, if you are using `moderncv` class then, `\photo[64pt]{picture.jpeg}` will serve your purpose. Place it before `\begin{document}` Thanks.

Comment: You can just C&P your code into the post. Mark it as you already did as code. But you should however only post the necessary part of the code. As currently written, there's still no documentclass.

Comment: Hi TeXnician, thanks for your comment. I put the complete code in a post below.

Answer (score 1):

Style `casual` knows a default option `right` and option `left` to write the name right or left on the cv.  You need option `left`.

You can activate option `left` with

```
\makeatletter\@lefttrue\@rightfalse\makeatother % <=====================
```

before calling `\makecvtitle`.

To place the image use call package `textpos` with (use `texdoc textpos` for documentation)

```
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos} % <==============================
```

Now you can use

```
\begin{textblock}{0}(11.4,3.1) % left-image, top-image
  \includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image-golden-upright}\par
\end{textblock}
```

to insert the wanted image.  Change `11.4` (in cm) to adjust the distance of the picture to the left paper size, and `3.1` (in cm) to adjust the distance between top of the pager and the image.

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos} % <==============================

\moderncvtheme{casual}

\moderncvcolor{blue}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\moderncvicons{marvosym}

\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=25mm,headsep=10mm, footskip=-0mm}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3,5cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{37pt}

\title{SEA Online Marketing Spezialist}
\firstname{Rebecca}
\familyname{Rekker}
\address{XXXXXXXXX}{XXXXXXXXX}
\mobile{XXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\email{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\upshape}

\makeatletter\@lefttrue\@rightfalse\makeatother % <=====================
\makecvtitle

\begin{textblock}{0}(11.4,3.1) % left-image, top-image
  \includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image-golden-upright}\par
\end{textblock}

\section{Persönliche Daten}
\cvitem{Geburtsdatum}{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\cvitem{Geburtsort}{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\cvitem{Staatsbürgerschaft}{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\cvitem{Familienstand}{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}

\section{Praxis und Berufserfahrung}

\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description Description Description Description Description \\Description Description Description Description Description}

\end{document}
```

you get the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Please note that all errors had vanished caused by your changed code for `\makecvtitle` ...